# class cast exception dialog android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

i am trying to create a spinner in dialog box

```
final Dialog viewDialog = new Dialog(NewActivity.this);
        viewDialog.getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
        viewDialog.setTitle("Nearest "+currentLocationType);
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.nearestlocs, null);
            viewDialog.setContentView(dialogView);
// error is in the next line
            Spinner addressSpinner = (Spinner) 
dialogView.findViewById(R.id.addressSpinner); 
        Button okButton = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.okbutton);
```

nearestlocs.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Spinner android:id="@+id/addressSpinner"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button android:text="Show route on Map" android:id="@+id/okbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

error log

```
 03-14 01:09:24.686: WARN/dalvikvm(6583): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
03-14 01:09:24.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6583): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-14 01:09:24.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6583): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.CheckBox
03-14 01:09:24.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6583):     at com.isproj3.NewActivity.displayNearestLocations(NewActivity.java:177)
03-14 01:09:24.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6583):     at com.isproj3.NewActivity.access$3(NewActivity.java:160)
```

could some one please tell what mistake am i committing? have spent over 2-3 hours to fix this, but in vain! i have no idea where the checkbox is coming into picture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just cleaned the project and re ran. Worked absolutely fine.

Comment: I just hit this bug,the code is casting findViewById to WebView and android complains java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.CheckBox

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps R.id.addressSpinner has the same value as a checkbox elsewhere in your app (another Activity, perhaps)?

Comment: @Poldie..nope..there is just one activity in the app and no other checkboxes elsewhere..